# How to initialiaze DatabaseProduct with primary key identity in code-first Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, linq-to-entities, code-first

I am using Entity Framework and want to initialize my database.

I have 3 classes

- Departments
- Categories
- Products

I am creating a new class for seeding the database inherited from class `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`. I am confused what to do in id column as it is mark as identity.

My class logic is as:

```
public class Product
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Key()]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required,StringLength(100),Display(Name="Name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public int? CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Categories Category { get; set; }
}

public class Categories
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public int? DepartmentID { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDatabaseInitializer:DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EwayContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(EwayContext context)
    {
        base.Seed(context);
    }

    private static List<Categories> Categories()
    {
        var categories= new List<Categories> {
            new Category{DepartmentId = //?? in what way map the items
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the temporary key as long as they also unique, the temporary key will be used to setup relationship before they're saved and will be replaced with identity key after being saved.

```
var department = new Department{ DepartmentID = 567 };
context.Departments.Add(department);

var category = new Category { CategoryID = 1234, DepartmentID = 567 };
context.Categories.Add(category);

var product = new Product { ProductID = 222, CategoryID = 1234 };
context.Products.Add(product);
```

More

- [Working with Entity Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd283139%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)